# Airflow start from first task

Tags: airflow

So im creating a DAG for daily backup,restore and delete, with branching

1. do daily backup restore and delete (always runs)
2. if its saturday do weekly backup,restore and delete
3. if its first day of month do montly backup,restore and delete

here is the cycle

```
    daily_backup_op.set_downstream(daily_restore_op)
    daily_restore_op.set_downstream(daily_delete_op)

    daily_delete_op.set_downstream(branching_op)
    branching_op.set_downstream([weekly_backup_op,monthly_backup_op,monthly_weekly_backup_op,end_task_op])

    weekly_backup_op.set_downstream(weekly_restore_op)
    weekly_restore_op.set_downstream(weekly_delete_op)

    monthly_backup_op.set_downstream(monthly_restore_op)
    monthly_restore_op.set_downstream(monthly_delete_op)

    monthly_weekly_backup_op.set_downstream(monthly_weekly_restore_op)
    monthly_weekly_restore_op.set_downstream(monthly_weekly_delete_op)

    weekly_delete_op.set_downstream(end_task_op)
    monthly_delete_op.set_downstream(end_task_op)
    monthly_weekly_delete_op.set_downstream(end_task_op)
```

when i test it for some reason it and it hits "else: return 'end'" , it wont reach the end_task_op, instead it keep restarting on starting from daily_backup_op

here is the branching code

```
def backup_restore_condition():
    if((DATE_TODAY == get_first_day_of_month()) and (get_weekday_number() == SATURDAY_WEEKDAY_NUMBER)):
        return 'monthly_weekly_backup'
    elif(DATE_TODAY == get_first_day_of_month()):
        return 'monthly_backup'
    elif(get_weekday_number() == SATURDAY_WEEKDAY_NUMBER):
        return 'weekly_backup'
    else:
        return 'end'
```

for the end_task_op

```
end_task_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='end',
        python_callable=end_task
    )
```

```
def end_task():
    print("task end succesfully")
```

full cycle image
[DAG image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X3wN.png)

am i missing something?

Comment: Not related to the question, but it is a good practice to not use set_downstrean and so on, but using bitshift composition: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#bitshift-composition

Comment: Can you share complete DAG to see where backup_restore_condition() is called?

Comment: @PriyaAgarwal https://github.com/ad17-2/dag-testing
there u go sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In end_task_op, you have to define a trigger_rule as NONE_FAILED which signifies 'run the task when all the parent task are succeeded or skipped'.
As Javier suggested, its better to use bitshift composition as it increases readability and reduces lines of code. Please see the DAG below which works in all the conditions:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
import datetime as dt

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': '2020-06-02'
}

dag = DAG(
    'backup_restore_delete_db',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    default_args=args
)
def daily_backup():
    print('daily backup')
def daily_restore():
    print('restore daily backup')
def daily_delete():
    print('delete 7 days old backup')
def weekly_backup():
    print('weekly backup')
def weekly_restore():
    print('restore weekly backup')
def weekly_delete():
    print('delete 7 week old backup')
def monthly_backup():
    print('monthly backup')
def monthly_restore():
    print('restore monthly backup')
def monthly_delete():
    print('delete 7 month old backup')
def monthly_weekly_backup():
    print('monthlyweekly backup')
def monthly_weekly_restore():
    print('restore monthlyweekly backup')
def monthly_weekly_delete():
    print('delete 7 monthlyweekly old backup')
def end_task():
    print("task end succesfully")

def branch_func():
    if (dt.date.today().strftime("%d") == "01") and (dt.date.today().isoweekday() == 6):
        return 'monthly_weekly_backup'
    elif (dt.date.today().strftime("%d") == "01"):
        return 'monthly_backup'
    elif (dt.date.today().isoweekday() == 6):
        return 'weekly_backup'
    else:
        return 'end_task'

daily_backup_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='daily_backup',
        python_callable=daily_backup,
        dag=dag
    )
weekly_backup_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='weekly_backup',
        python_callable=weekly_backup,
        dag=dag
    )

monthly_backup_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='monthly_backup',
        python_callable=monthly_backup,
        dag=dag
    )
daily_restore_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='daily_restore',
        python_callable=daily_restore,
        dag=dag
    )

weekly_restore_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='weekly_restore',
        python_callable=weekly_restore,
        dag=dag
    )

monthly_restore_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='monthly_restore',
        python_callable=monthly_restore,
        dag=dag
    )

daily_delete_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='daily_delete',
        python_callable=daily_delete,
        dag=dag
    )

weekly_delete_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='weekly_delete',
        python_callable=weekly_delete,
        dag=dag
    )

monthly_delete_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='monthly_delete',
        python_callable=monthly_delete,
        dag=dag
    )

monthly_weekly_backup_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='monthly_weekly_backup',
        python_callable=monthly_weekly_backup,
        dag=dag
    )

monthly_weekly_restore_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='monthly_weekly_restore',
        python_callable=monthly_weekly_restore,
        dag=dag 
    )

monthly_weekly_delete_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='monthly_weekly_delete',
        python_callable=monthly_weekly_delete,
        dag=dag 
    )

end_task_op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='end_task',
        python_callable=end_task,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED,
        dag=dag
    )

branching_op = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch_func',
        python_callable=branch_func,
        dag=dag
    )

daily_backup_op >> daily_restore_op >> daily_delete_op >> branching_op
branching_op >> monthly_weekly_backup_op >> monthly_weekly_restore_op >> monthly_weekly_delete_op >> end_task_op
branching_op >> monthly_backup_op >> monthly_restore_op >> monthly_delete_op >> end_task_op
branching_op >> weekly_backup_op >> weekly_restore_op >> weekly_delete_op >> end_task_op
branching_op >> end_task_op
```

Comment: yes this actually worked, i learned something there thankyou sir!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of help.